# CORS support for Apache CXF 2.4 (JAX-RS 1.1)

Tags: java, rest, cors, jax-rs, cxf

I'm looking for an open source implementation of CORS for Apache CXF 2.4.x (JAX-RS 1.1) like the [CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/rt/rs/security/cors/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/rs/security/cors/CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter.java) (Apache CXF >2.5.0).

Unfortunately I can't update Apache CXF because of JBoss 7.1.1, which uses Apache CXF 2.4.6.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Workaround. I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-security-cors</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and I replaced

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-common-utilities</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-common-utilities</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

All my tests passed and I hope that cxf-common-utilities is backward compatible.